# Python3 Cannot concatenate error? How to fix?

Tags: function, python-3.x, join, concatenation

Given this function that I built, I'm getting an error for the last return statement saying that I can't join them together. Is there another way I can do this?

```
def simple_pig_latin(input, sep=' ', end='.'):
words=input.split(sep)
Vowels= ('a','e','i','o','u')
Digit= (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
cons=('b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z')
characters= ('!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','.')
new_sentence=[]

for word in words:
    if word:
        if word[0]==" ":
            new_word=word   
        else:
            if word[0] in Vowels:
                new_word= word+"way"

            elif word[0] in Digit:
                new_word= word

            elif word[0] in cons:
                first_letter=word[0] #saves the first letter
                change= str(word) #change to string                     
                rem= change.replace(first_letter,'')#remove the first letter
                put_last= rem+first_letter #add letter to end
                new_word= put_last+ "ay"

            elif word[0] in characters:
                new_word= word

            new_sentence= new_sentence + new_word+ sep
    else:
        new_sentence.append(word)

return sep.join(new_sentence)+end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. (You need to use ''.join() )

```
def simple_pig_latin(input, sep=' ', end='.'):
    words=input.split(sep)
    Vowels= ('a','e','i','o','u')
    Digit= (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    cons=('b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z')
    characters= ('!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','.')
    new_sentence=[]
    for word in words:
        if word:
            if word[0]==" ":
                new_word=word
            else:
                if word[0] in Vowels:
                    new_word= word+"way"
                elif word[0] in Digit:
                    new_word= word
                elif word[0] in cons:
                    first_letter=word[0] #saves the first letter
                    change= str(word) #change to string
                    rem= change.replace(first_letter,'')#remove the first letter
                    put_last= rem+first_letter #add letter to end
                    new_word= put_last+ "ay"
                elif word[0] in characters:
                    new_word= word
                new_sentence= ''.join(new_sentence) + ''.join(new_word) + ''.join(sep)
        else:
            new_sentence.append(word)

    "".join(new_sentence)
    return new_sentence




    print simple_pig_latin("welcome to the jungle.")  # Sample call to func
```

results in

```
    lcomeway otay hetay ungle.jay
```

**EDIT 1**

Alternate way

```
def simple_pig_latin(input, sep=' ', end='.'):
    words = input.split(sep)
    sentence =""
    for word in words:
        endString= str(word[1:])
        them=endString, str(word[0:1]), 'ay'
        newWords="".join(them)
        sentence = sentence + sep + newWords
    sentence = sentence + end
    return sentence


    print simple_pig_latin("I like this ")
```

Comment: I cannot use print statements, only return @Cyrus

Comment: Sorry, print was there for debugging. removed it, please try it. It works (as long as the output you expect is what i got (welcome to the jungle. returned as elcomeway otay hetay ungle.jay

Comment: There should be no dot in front of jay

Comment: Please share a sample input and expected output. i suspect the issue is with the coding above, rather than the error about joining that you were getting earlier.

Comment: Examples: "I like this" separator is space gives iway ikelay histay. Period is at end... Another example is "I-like-this" separator is - and end is . Gives iway-ikelay-histay.

Comment: May i propose you try my "Alternate way" ? much shorter code.

Comment: I like your way but I can't use it because I have other conditionals to use in certain scenarios. Like starts with vowels add way

Comment: Ok. However, your initial question seems to be resolved. There is no concatenation error with the suggested fix in syntax.